# uiscrollview scrollRectToVisible: method not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

When the user touches the screen, I want to scroll the screen downwards. I implemented touchesBegan:withEvent: method in my vc and this is what I came up with.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
       UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
       scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
       [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
       [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,100,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: This will only work if the user is touching the view that is managed by the view controller, i.e. self.view. I'm guessing self.view has some subviews, so they are getting the touch events instead. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, i needed to make sure the i kept the size the same when i was scrolling rect to visible